# Paper Signals / Google Assistent not recognizing commands

Tags: android, user-interface, google-assistant-sdk

We are building a [Paper Signal](https://papersignals.withgoogle.com):

While anything else has worked as expected, the Google Assistent doesn't recognize the words "Talk to Paper Signals" and "Create a new Paper Signal" as described [here](https://papersignals.withgoogle.com/getstarted#connect). Has anyone experienced similar issues? Our default language is German.

How can I activate an Action for the Paper Signals if not by the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that only Google Assistent for English(US) was able to understand the commands, even English(DE) didn't work.